# Linear ODE $x_t(t,T)-ax(t,T)=-1$, $x(T,T)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the solution for $x_t(t,T)-ax(t,T)=-1$, where $x(T,T)=0$. That is, for a fixed T, a linear ODE in the t-variable. I don't understand how I could solve this if the lower bound is the one that is changing. I tried it using an integrating factor $e^{-at}$ but without success. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution (using an integrating factor) is given by $$x(t,T) = \frac{1}{a} + Ce^{at}$$ Evaluating $x \lvert_{t = T}$ \begin{align} x(T,T) &= \frac{1}{a} + Ce^{aT} \\ &= 0 \\ \implies C &= \frac{-e^{-aT}}{a} \\ \implies x(t,T) &=  \frac{1}{a} - \frac{e^{a(t-T)}}{a} \end{align}

Comment: Hmm, yes that is the solution as it should be. So, I should use an integral from 0 to t instead of t to T?

Comment: I'm guessing the integration bounds was the thing that was confusing you. You don't need bounds on the integral whatsoever. You have \begin{align} x_{t}-ax &= -1 \\ \implies (e^{-at}x)_{t} &= -e^{-at} \\ \implies \int (e^{-at}x)_{t} dt &= \int -e^{-at} dt \\ \implies e^{-at}x &= \frac{e^{-at}}{a} + C \\ \implies x &=  \frac{1}{a} + Ce^{at} \end{align} Then you can evaluate $x \lvert_{t = T}$.

Comment: Please avoid answering questions in comments. Thank you.